# How to make `zsh` immediately show all completions, without first inserting the common prefix?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I have `zsh` set up with Oh-My-Zsh.
The `z` plugin allows me to jump to recently used directories.

When I type `z name<TAB>`,  it autocompletes `name` from the list of recently visited dirs by matching `name` against the list.

Sometimes the result contains only a single entry, when I know there should be multiple. I have debugged the `$reply` variable and it happens if all entries have the same prefix, e.g. `/path/to/dir`, containing dirs with `name`
In this case there is only the prefix in the autocomplete menu instead of full list of matched dirs. Hitting `<TAB>` again after expansion, triggers a new call to `z` script complete function now with the full common prefix instead of my search query , e.g. `/path/to/dir`

When I press <Shift+Tab> which is bound to `reverse-menu-complete`
`zsh` properly selects the last item and shows the full list.

Is there a way to make Tab immediately show all completions, without first inserting the common prefix?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc` file, *after* sourcing Oh-My-Zsh:

```bash
bindkey '\t' menu-complete
```

Now <kbd>Tab</kbd> will behave exactly the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, but in the opposite direction.

---

Alternatively, for more control over how completion behaves, install my [Zsh Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete).